# I can't loop through JSON Array for next Array

Tags: java, android, json, getjson

I try to learn [Loop through a JSON object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722228/loop-through-a-json-object-in-java) for loop this case.But My json loop first array(ident AFL274) and stop not loop next array(CQH8971)(in json data have 2 arrays)I call this function by button.

this for call for json

```
public String getInfo(String url) {  
    try {
        String result  = HttpGet(url);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject val = json.getJSONObject("SearchResult");
        JSONArray data = val.getJSONArray("aircraft");

        for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject data1 = data.getJSONObject(i);
            String ans = data1.getString("ident");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return ans;
}
```

and this JSON:

```
{
    "SearchResult": {
        "next_offset": -1,
        "aircraft": [
            { 
                "ident": "AFL274", 
                "type": "B77W" 
            },
            { 
                "ident": "CQH8971", 
                "type": "A320"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase what your problem is. Also, show the rest of your JSON.

Comment: You keep overwriting the variable with this line `String ans = data1.getString("ident");` instead of adding each result to an array, also you only return `ans` variable from your method. I hope you call this method from a separate thread as well and not on the Main Thread.

Comment: @kabuto178 Mostly right, the overwrite to `String ans` is really moot as that variable is only scoped to the loop body - when he returns `ans` he's returning an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public String[] getInfo(String url) {  
    try {
        String result  = HttpGet(url);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject val = json.getJSONObject("SearchResult");
        JSONArray data = val.getJSONArray("aircraft");
        int arrayLength = data.length();
        String[] strAryAns = new String[arrayLength]; 

        for(int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)
        {
            JSONObject data1 = data.getJSONObject(i);
            strAryAns[i] = data1.getString("ident");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return strAryAns;
}
```